# How to make a custom field with multiple db fields in Django

Tags: django

I have a class:

```
class MyCustomType(object):
    a, b = 0, ""
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

I want to make a custom field class for `MyCustomType`.

```
class MyCustomField(models.Field):
    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        # magic
        return MyCustomType(a, b)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return self.parse_value(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, MyCustomType) or value is None:
            return value
        return self.parse_value(value)
```

How can I use two db fields for storing `a` and `b` data? `a` is an integer and `b` is a string?

Comment: do you have any django Model? not clear why you have a field with two fields inside

Comment: MyCustomType has a specific logic and it will be used at the different models and at the different places of source code. It is like some money field with amount and currency.

Comment: Got it. I think you may want to rethink your logic, maybe make sure your models have Amount and Currency field (like in your example), and make sure they implement a "conversion mixin" or whatever method you need.